# Using ValueDataSource to show skalar value

Tags: cuba-platform

I want to show a skalar values by using a label. The following example shows the sum of customer order amounts.

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.8/value_datasources.html

```
<dsContext>
<valueCollectionDatasource id="salesDs">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[select o.customer, sum(o.amount) from demo$Order o group by o.customer]]>
    </query>
    <properties>
        <property class="com.company.demo.entity.Customer" name="customer"/>
        <property datatype="decimal" name="sum"/>
    </properties>
</valueCollectionDatasource>
```

here I want to bind the loaded data to the label:

```
        <label datasource="salesDs"
               property="name"/>
```

but nothing is shown.

Why is the label value empty? (salesDs is correctly loaded, I can step through with intelliJ...)

I also tried to get the loaded data from the datasource, but I can't find the correct way.

```
salesDs.getItem() //returns null
salesDs.getItems() //retruns a collection of KeyValueEntries
```

But, what is the correct way to get my data from a KeyValueEntry?

Comment: i think ValueCollectionDatasources (as the name supplies) are only for collections of data. The datasource of the label component on the other hand is for setting / reading a property of a Datasource (in particular datasources for a single entity). In particular there is no ValueDatasource class in the FW, but only Collection-, Group-, and Hierachical ones. Besides that: the property="name" should be something else, right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The label has a DataSource, no CollectionDatasource, that can't work. Is it possible to define a NestedDatasource for the ValueCollectionDatasoure? I tried, studio says no...

Answer (score 1):

It would work if you selected an item in the collection datasource (no matter ValueCollectionDatasource or a normal one). It can be done programmatically via `setItem()` or by some visual component also connected to the same datasource.

For example, in the below screen the label shows the name of the customer currently selected in the table:

```xml
<dsContext>
    <valueCollectionDatasource id="customersDs">
        <query>
            <![CDATA[select e.name, e.email 
                     from sales$Customer e]]>
        </query>
        <properties>
            <property datatype="string"
                      name="name"/>
            <property datatype="string"
                      name="email"/>
        </properties>
    </valueCollectionDatasource>
</dsContext>
<layout expand="customersTable" spacing="true">
    <table id="customersTable" width="100%">
        <columns>
            <column id="name"/>
            <column id="email"/>
        </columns>
        <rows datasource="customersDs"/>
    </table>
    <groupBox caption="Label">
        <label id="nameLab"
               datasource="customersDs"
               property="name"/>
    </groupBox>
</layout>
```